# I Want to send this object in child component and in data another object is coming

Tags: angular

const respObj = {
            id: "multiLineChart",
            data: response,
            width: 1050,
            height: 500
          }

Comment: Can you elaborate your question further?

Comment: Actually I want to send this object from parent to child  but When I am using then I am getting the empty object.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out @Input property which does exactly what you need!
Also, this should be helpful:
 https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction.

Comment: fetchMultiLineData() {
    this.eventService.getMultiLineData2().subscribe(
      response => {
        if (response) {
          const respObj = {
            id: "multiLineChart",
            data: response,
            width: 1050,
            height: 500
          }
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }